Can't use notations and define implies_tautology theorem
Andrej Bauer has helped me with this code:
Section Formula.
(* Atomic proposition. *)
Context {atom : Set}.
(* Parameter atom : Set. *)

(* We assume atomic propositions form a set with decidable equality. *)
Parameter atom_eq : forall (a b : atom), {a = b} + {a <> b}.

(* Propositional formulas *)
Inductive formula : Type :=
| f_atom : atom -> formula
| f_not  : formula -> formula
| f_imp  : formula -> formula -> formula.

Declare Scope formula_scope.
Open Scope formula_scope.
Declare Custom Entry formula_view.

(* Filling in notations according to priority *)
Notation "x" := x (x ident, in custom formula_view at level 0).
Notation "( p )" := p (p custom formula_view at level 5, in custom formula_view at level 0).
Notation "~ p" := (f_not p) (p custom formula_view at level 1, in custom formula_view at level 1).

(*
Implication is weaker the conjunction and disjunction, but we need it for their definitions
that's why introduce it's notation beforehand
 *)
Notation "p -> q" := (f_imp p q) (q custom formula_view at level 4, in custom formula_view at level 4).

Notation "'$' p '$'" := p (format "'$' p '$'", p custom formula_view at level 5, at level 0).

Definition conjunction (A B: formula) : formula := $~(A -> ~B)$.
Notation "A /\ B" := (conjunction A B) (B custom formula_view at level 2, in custom formula_view at level 2, left associativity) : formula_scope.

Definition disjunction (A B: formula) : formula := $~A -> B$.
Notation "A \/ B" := (disjunction A B) (B custom formula_view at level 3, in custom formula_view at level 3, left associativity) : formula_scope.

Definition equivalence (A B: formula) : formula := $(A -> B) /\ (B -> A)$.
Notation "A <-> B" := (equivalence A B) (B custom formula_view at level 5, in custom formula_view at level 5, left associativity) : formula_scope.

(* Equality of formulas is decidable. *)
Lemma formula_eq (A B : formula) : {A = B} + {A <> B}.
Proof.
  decide equality.
  now apply atom_eq.
Qed.

(* Instead of working with lists of assumptions we shall work with
   sets of assumptions. A set of formulas can be represented by its
   characteristic map formula -> Prop. *)

(* Element-hood relation between a formula and a set of formulas. *)
Definition elem (A : formula) (Γ : formula -> Prop) := Γ A.
Infix "∈" := elem (at level 77) : formula_scope.

(* The empty context. *)
Definition empty : formula -> Prop := fun _ => False.

(* The union of two sets of formulas. *)
Definition union (Γ Δ : formula -> Prop) (A : formula) := A ∈ Γ \/ A ∈ Δ.
Infix "∪" := union (at level 78, left associativity) : formula_scope.

(* The subset relation between sets of formulas. *)
Definition subset (Γ Δ : formula -> Prop) :=
  forall A, A ∈ Γ -> A ∈ Δ.
Infix "⊆" := subset (at level 79) : formula_scope.

Fixpoint eval (value : atom -> bool) (f : formula) : bool :=
  match f with
  | f_atom a => value a
  | f_not f => negb (eval value f)
  | f_imp f1 f2 => implb (eval value f1) (eval value f2)
end.

Definition logically_implies (A : formula) (B : formula) :=
  forall v : atom -> bool, is_true (eval v A) -> is_true (eval v A).

Definition tautology (f : formula) :=
  forall v : atom -> bool, is_true (eval v f).
End Formula.

(* Example on how to write an actual formula and evaluate it. *)

(* A type with three atoms. *)
Inductive atom3 : Set :=
  | x1 : atom3
  | x2 : atom3
  | x3 : atom3.

Check @eval.
(* A valuation. *)
Definition val3 (x : atom3) : bool :=
  match x with
  | x1 => true
  | x2 => false
  | x3 => false
  end.

Check @logically_implies.
Check @tautology.
(* Evaluate ¬ (x₁ ⇒ x₂) at v. *)
Eval compute in eval val3 (f_not (f_imp (f_atom x1) (f_atom x2))).

Theorem implies_tautology (vals: Set) A B : (@logically_implies vals A B) <-> (@tautology vals (f_imp A -> B)).
Proof.

What I don't understand:

How to use notations outside of Section? For example, if I would like to write:

Eval compute in eval val3 $~(x1 -> x2)$.
(* instead of *)
Eval compute in eval val3 (f_not (f_imp (f_atom x1) (f_atom x2))).


Should I use Section if I would need to use this file in another file of should I use a Module instead? How to use a Context inside a Module in this case?

I read the manual about Context and generalization. As I can see:


Check @logically_implies.
@logically_implies
     : forall atom : Set, formula -> formula -> Prop


atom becomes any Set after generalization. How to defined a theorem: formula A logically implies formula B if and only if the formula A -> B is a tautology? I tried:
Theorem implies_tautology A B : (logically_implies A B) <-> (tautology (f_imp A B)).

Error: Cannot infer the implicit parameter atom of tautology whose type is "Set".

I should add some forall statement to introduce a set of values for formulas, but where?


Notations do not survive closing a section if they were declared inside the section, as described here. You need to declare again the notation after closing the section.
The (global) content of sections will be imported normally when you import the file. The decision whether to use modules or not depends on the organization you want for your development, i.e. how you want objects to be grouped together. To use Context in a module, you can open a section.
In you statement of implies_tautology, there is no atom, so Coq does not know what to put in place of the atom implicit argument of tautology. You need to specify at least once what atom is and Coq will infer the rest. For instance, Theorem implies_tautology (vals: Set) (A B : @formula vals) : (logically_implies A B) <-> (tautology (f_imp A B)). should work.


Can you write, how to define implies_tautology theorem, so it didn't cause syntax error?

I misunderstood the issue, the arguments are indeed implicit since you marked atom as implicit in the Context command. I edited the answer. Your first block of code almost compiles, there is just a stray arrow in your definition of implies_tautology.

I it possible to use something instead of Context {atom : Set}. and change the block Section to Module?

You need a section anyway to have section variables.
